# Which one is correct $\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{n}× n^2$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{k} (2^{n}× n^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, summation, notation

I have $2$ questions about notation.

*Question 1.*

Suppose, numbers are as follows.

> $\left\{3\right\}\longrightarrow7$
>
> $\left\{3,6\right\}\longrightarrow9$
>
> $\left\{3,6,7\right\}\longrightarrow11$
>
> $\left\{3,6,7,5\right\}\longrightarrow15$
>
> $...............$
>
> $\left\{p_1,p_2,p_3,...p_n\right\}\longrightarrow q_n$

And $p_1,p_2,...,p_{n}$ are arbitrary natural numbers.But, the value $q_n$ depend on the values of ${p_1,p_2,...,p_n}.$

I want to write a notation.

I think, I can write, for example,

> $$f(p_1,p_2,...p_n)=q_n$$ like a function.Is it correct or ıs there an other notation?

*Question 2.*

Which notation is correct?

> $\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{n}× n^2$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{k} (2^{n}× n^2)$

and

> $\sum_{n=1}^{k} 2^{n}+n^2$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{k} (2^{n}+n^2)$

Comment: You're contradicting yourself by explaining the relationship of $p_1,\dots,p_n$ and $q_n$.

Comment: I 'm sorry for this, can you help me improve question..Maybe I did not express it correctly.

Comment: First you say that the values of $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ depend on $q_n.$  The you say that $q_n$ depends on $p_1, \cdots, p_n.$  It seems unlikely you mean both of these statements.  It looks like the $q_k$ depend on the $p_k.$  Am I right?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, yes you are right! English is my second language.I'm sorry for this.

Comment: I fixed the mistake

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I try fixed the mistake.

Comment: @Math No need to apologize to me.  I just wanted to clarify things.

Comment: @Math Yes, now it makes sense and your idea is right.

Comment: @TheGeekGreet the Is the first Sigma notation correct?

Comment: @Math It doesn't really matter...you can write it without bracket but they mean both the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **A word of warning to question 2:** The subscript $n$ in
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^k 2^n+n^2
> \end{align*}
>
> does not tell anything about the scope of the sigma operator $\Sigma$.
>
> - The scope of the sigma operator $\Sigma$ is solely defined via *[arithmetic precedence rules](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-rules-2009-1.pdf)*. It is given by the expression that follows immediately the $\Sigma$ and is valid respecting the arithmetic precedence rules up to an operator with precedence level equal to '$+$' or up to the end if no such operator follows.

This implies that
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^k 2^n}+n^2&=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^k \left(2^n\right)}+n^2=\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^k 2^n\right)}+n^2\\
&=\color{blue}{2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^k}+n^2
\end{align*}
The scope of the Sigma symbol does not extend to $n^2$, which is a variable by its own independent of the index $n$ (and a **bad naming** style).

On the other hand according to the arithmetic precedence rules we have
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^k \left(2^n+n^2\right)&=(2^1+1^2)+(2^2+2^2)\cdots (2^k+k^2)\\
  &=2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^k+1^2+2^2+\cdots+k^2\\
  &=\sum_{n=1}^k 2^n +\sum_{n=1}^k n^2
  \end{align*}

> We conclude in general we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^k 2^n+n^2\ne\sum_{n=1}^k \left(2^n+n^2\right)
> \end{align*}

Since multiplication has higher precedence level than addition we obtain
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^k2^n\cdot n^2&=\sum_{n=1}^k\left(2^n\cdot n^2\right)
  =2^1\cdot1^2+2^2\cdot 2^2+\cdots 2^k\cdot k^2
  \end{align*}

> **Hints to question 1:**
>
> The representation
>   \begin{align*}
>   f(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)=q_n
>   \end{align*}
>   indicates a function $f:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Here the argument of $f$ is an $n$-tuple $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ where order matters. This does not match the mapping of
>   \begin{align*}
>   \{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}\rightarrow q_n
>   \end{align*}
>   where the left-hand side is an *unordered* set.
>
> We could write
>   \begin{align*}
> &f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus\emptyset\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
> &f(\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\})=q_n  
> \end{align*}
>
> Here the argument is a set consisting of $n$ natural numbers. In order to avoid ambiguities we also have to specify in this case that $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ are pairwise different.

Comment: ***Thank you sooo much, for excellent, informative and amazing answer!***

Comment: @Math: You;re welcome. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For question 1, yes, we can write it as a function $f$ with domain $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb N^k$ and codomain $\mathbb N$.

That is, $f:\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb N^k \to\mathbb N$.

For question 2, it's less ambiguous with parentheses in both cases.
Still, it's not unusual that the parentheses are left out in both cases, which is really a bit of abuse of notation. But since the $n$ is bound to the summation symbol, someone who reads it can deduce that the parentheses will be intended even if they are left out.

Comment: As to the fits part, the way the question is written, it appears that the domain is $\mathcal P(\mathbb N).$  I think the question was edited after you posted your answer.

Comment: @IlkeSerena I edited question. I'm sorry for this.

Comment: @IlikeSerena: Please note $n$ is *not* necessarily bounded by the summation symbol.

Comment: Indeed @saulspatz, the question was edited, and I wonder if unordered sets are intended.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, my point is that if n is undefined in the context, then there is no ambiguity. And it'd be bad practice if it is. With normal addition and multiplication we really get something different, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @IlikeSerena: With respect to this context $n$ and $k$ have precisely the same status of *definedness*. They both are free variables contrary to the index $n$ which is a bounded variable.